# Cannot create abstract class?

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, wcf-client

i am working on a wcf project

everything went well before an attempt to calling the service with a large object which exceeded the maxStringContentLength.

to fix that problem, i modify the config files in both client and server side to change that value from the default 8192 to 2M

then i get a FaultException exception that says "cannot create abstract class", during the call to my service, and before any of my service code is executed

the detail of the exception says it might be an exception created by setting IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults to true and its value is System.MemberAccessException

well, due to some locale reasons, this isn't the exact exception message, i have translated that to english to mean something similar

any suggestions on what might the problem be? thanks

Comment: We are going to need some more information in order to figure this out. Could you please post the code for your service contract and implementation?

Comment: Could you post your service skeleton and the configuration of your service in the config files?

Comment: thanks. this has been resolved. it actually turns out to be mistakes in my own codes. since abstract data contracts are transformed to normal classes in client side, some of them get incorrectly instantiated. i thought it would be a problem in my config file before realizing the real problem and finding a lot of debate over why wcf doesn't support the share of abstractness between server and client data contracts

Comment: Add an answer and mark it as excepted so people know that this is resolved, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been resolved. It's cause is that data contracts that are defined to be abstract classes at wcf server side will be transformed to concrete classes if you use visual studio to automatically generate the service reference at client side. Those concrete classes could be unintentionally instantiated, which causes the runtime exception

Comment: so, is there any concrete solution/workaround for this issue? I have no idea what I can do about it by reading your answer.. ?